# How can i get directory name of markdown file in gatsby?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

i have a posts directory like:

```
src
  -posts
    -post-a
      index.md
      demo.jpg
    -post-b
      index.md
      logo.jpg
  -pages
    index.js
    // ...
```

i want to let the directory name post-a/post-b as index.md's id, how can i do?

here is my `gatsby-config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        name: 'posts',
        path: `${__dirname}/src/posts`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-transformer-remark',
      options: {
        commonmark: true,
        footnotes: true,
        pedantic: true,
        gfm: true,
        plugins: [],
      },
    },
    'gatsby-transformer-sharp',
    'gatsby-plugin-sharp',
    'gatsby-plugin-react-helmet',
  ],
};
```

[image]

but `allMarkdownRemark.edges.node` do not have the directory info.

Comment: Can you use `fileAbsolutePath`?

Comment: @ksav i think it can use `fileAbsolutePath`, but need to do something with it. there are some gatsby project have `allMarkdownRemark.edges.node.fields` that include the directory info, but my project do not have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `createFilePath` function from `gatsby-source-filesystem` to construct your slug and add it to `markdownRemark.fields` by using `onCreateNode` API. The official blog starter also does that: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog/blob/04ace724603b46198665e052006031ba7e644f9d/gatsby-node.js#L53-L64

```
exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, actions, getNode }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions

  if (node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark`) {
    const value = createFilePath({ node, getNode })
    createNodeField({
      name: `slug`,
      node,
      value,
    })
  }
}
```

The slug now contains the directory name of your blog posts.

---

Your original question:

You can use union types to access the parent, e.g.:

```
{
  allMarkdownRemark {
    nodes {
      parent {
        ... on File {
          dir
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```